Can definitions in the Oxford Dictionary of the English Language be considered definitive in informal philosophical presentations?
I ran into an interesting problem recently, in which several definitions I extrapolated from the subject dictionary catastrophically failed to support the validity of my position.  Full disclosure, I did not reference the source in my presentation, because the presentation was not a white paper, but rather an informal open discussion.

You answer your own question. So what would you want us to add? [From me +1; but thats a side issue...]  By and large if you take the rule of thumb that dictionary is for people who want to learn the language (here English) not people who want to explore philosophy, that should guide the usage

Dictionaries tell you how words are commonly used. That is all. If that's what you were talking about, great. If not, how were you trying to use them?

Philosophers very often use words with "non-standrad" meaning: in this case it is necessary to state explicitly the intended meaning.

No definition is definitive or true. The only requirement is that they are accepted by all parties in a conversation. Of course, a definition being considered widely accepted enough to be put in a public, authoritative reference document (the dictionary) is more likely to meet this requirement.

You are better off with Oxford Dictionary of Philosophy. But even then, one reason philosophers write lengthy texts is to fix their terms, which are commonly nuanced compared not just to colloquial English but even to similar terms used by other philosophers. Consulting SEP on the use of terms in contexts you intend to use them in may help further, but only primary sources are the ultimate authority.

I think we're missing too much context. Perhaps you were giving a presentation of your position, and you were using a word relevant to the conversation, but you were referencing a definition for that word that was entirely unrelated to the context of the rest of the conversation. Words have multiple meanings - just because you find a definition doesn't mean you're using the right definition for the overall context of the discussion.

A dictionary is not an authoritative text on the meaning of words; it's a guidebook for common usage. In philosophical discussions meaning is subject to contestation, and it is up to the speaker to ground his meanings in something substantial: hermeneutics or dialectics; evidentiary support; normative, moral, or aesthetic arguments; structural consistency; etc.
It's like any other professional activity… A lay person sees a fish and reads the dictionary definition: "a limbless cold-blooded vertebrate animal with gills and fins and living wholly in water"; a marine biologist sees a wide array of species in an ecosystem, and thinks that definition is tawdry and superficial. If the dictionary disagrees with what you're trying to say, that only means you're using words badly. Don't let a thesis be carried by words. A thesis should be carried by arguments crafted to give meanings to words, not the other way around.

Philosophy class taught me successfull communication meant accurate transmission of a concept or series of concepts and accurate reciept.
The lesson I learned was this... the "correct" definition is not what matters.  My definition is not what matters.  Oxford's definition matters a fair bit, but not exhaustively so... What really matters is the definition / interpretation that will take place in the mind of the person receiving the communication.
If I say "put it in the boot", and am speaking to an American or Canadian... it matters zero that sixty-seven million English speakers in the UK would understand me no problem.  What matters is who I am speaking to.  My audience.
If there is potential for a term to be taken incorrectly... a helpful tool in an article or paper that needs the term understood a specific way, is a glossary of terms.
It is not really intended to act as a dictionary... but it can be used to do that job and cement the sanctity of the rest of the paper.  Protect it against things such as changes in definitions over time, or differences in definitions by region.  (Like "boot, lorrie, lift, and rouser")
My main point... when I write... what my words mean to me... is about 1/100th as important as what will be heard by a reader.
Sometimes I will use a definition in place of the word that could fill the role.  In case others attach incorrect baggage to the word.
Instead of "God" I am likely to say "Creator and Designer and Supernatural Supreme Universal Entity".  Rather than be fuzzy, or be misheard.
Instead of "Universe" I almost exclusively use "the cosmos and all within".  Some people tend to want to turn the cosmos and all within, into a single "thing" that might act or ponder as a single "thing".
I call it word-baggage.  When "the masses" have put funny attachments upon the recorded definition of a word.  Noting "word-baggage" is my own term, not an official philosophical label.
EDIT:  Bonus considerations.
The word set holds the record with a redorded 430 distinct definitions (and some reports suggest this has ballooned out to 464, since getting put in the book)
https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/english-word-with-the-most-meanings
Words evolve.  There are regional definitions, and others that are national or globally consistent.  But thos consistency relationships can change and morph with time.  A good example of a word that is quite in flux at the moment is "gender".
If one took a snapshot of definitions of the word "gender" from 20 different dictionaries 20 years ago... and then taken a repeat snapshot of the same definition in those same dictionaries, every year since... you would see a migration and movement towards a more open and unified definition, moving around the world.  (This is not in any way a comment on the observation, it is just a good example of evolution of definiton of a word, coupled with migration of the evolution).
And lends strength to the suggestion of a "glossary" or "list of used definitions" included in material, when sensible.

The usual term for "word-baggage" is "connotation" (as distinguished from "denotation", the "actual meaning" / dictionary definition of a word). Skinny, thin, and narrow have the same denotation, but different connotations.

@wizzwizz4 Yes I agree, but there can be a bit more... in the case of "the universe" versus "the cosmos and all within"... denotation is the same... one has more opportunity for varied connotations that the other.  (that may be just my opinion, on the specific example).  Luckily, since "word-baggage" is my own term, I get to set the definition... I call it, yes, connotation, but also a little more".   (Grins).

Dictionary definitions are usually informal, which prevents their use in formal deductive systems. There do exist formal dictionaries, but they don't cover entire natural languages; instead, they are focused on specific fields of endeavor and provide definitions which allow folks in those fields to make progress.

Not necessarily — in philosophy, words are often the subject of the discussion (what is beauty, love, reality, consciousness etc.).
I also note that almost all words, let alone sentences formed from them, have more than one meaning. Many philosophical problems can be solved or at least explained by assigning specific, unmistakable meanings to the terms used.
On the other hand there is a whole school of philosophy claiming that we should use ordinary words (like "know") in their ordinary meanings, and that many philosophical problems only arise because philosophers use them in a different way that causes the very problems they then try to solve.
There is also the problem of arguing in language about language, specifically its limits, and the relation between speaking and thinking; a problem Wittgenstein felt most philosophers had not appreciated properly.
In short: No, the dictionary definition will not get you far in philosophy.

Hopefully not.
In the dozens of times I've found conflicts, it has always seemed to me that Chambers' was more accurate or more clear; often, both.
Meanwhile, why might the failure of your extrapolation from the subject dictionary say more about the dictionary than your power of extrapolation? Either way, how could your 'Full disclosure…' come into this?
